# Advanced row limiting

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have table with GPS data: coordinates, direction, speed and datetime. I want to select 25 rows of many.
It should return first, last and other 23 rows in between. It could use datetime value to make selection more effective  (e.g. skip rows with small time span). Idea is to get limited number of coordinates, but still be able to view route on map.

Comment: You can use the `Limit` with `Union` to get what you want.

Comment: Do you mean getting fairly well-distributed 23 points between start and end?

Comment: Microsoft really doesn't have anything to do with MySQL.  Please tag the question with the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 23
UNION 
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column ASC LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But it is a very naive way.

Comment: Note that LIMIT is a MySQL construct.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by (case when column in (mincol, maxcol) then 1 else 0 end order by newid()) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   min(column) over () as mincol,
                   max(column) over () as maxcol
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 23;
```

If you really want 25 rows, then the logic is tricky.  You need to get all rows, if there are fewer than 25.  You need to be sure that a random sample doesn't include the first and last rows.  This just puts the min and max values in a separate partition, so they numbered as 1 and 2.  So, the final `where` clause gets all of them.

The following is equivalent, but perhaps clearer in intent:

```
where seqnum <= 23 or column in (mincol, maxcol)
```

Comment: Please notice that most of the syntax in this answer works only for Sql Server, not MySQL.